# Ubuntu server drop ping for specified interface

Tags: server, ufw, ping

I am searching for a possibility to drop the ping packets for my ppp0 interface, but allow them for eth0.

I use ufw know that i can reject ping by changing lines in **/etc/ufw/before.rules**

But thats for all interfaces, i just want it to drop for ppp0.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use iptables?  It can differentiate per interface.  Something like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i ppp0 -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j REJECT
```

That works like a champ for me.